# How to import Alert / AlertTitle component with MaterialUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, snackbar

I am really confused - [this example](https://material-ui.com/components/snackbars/) for using React MaterialUI says I can use this for a Snackbar:

```
    <Snackbar message="Here is snackbar message" open={true} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={() => {}}>
        <Alert severity="error">
          <AlertTitle>Error</AlertTitle>
             This is an error alert — check it out!
        </Alert>
    </Snackbar>
```

but `@materialui/core` does not export an `Alert` or `AlertTitle` components:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Here is the link that talks about Alert / AlertTitle - but I cannot figure out how to import these components :(

https://material-ui.com/components/alert/

Comment: With Material UI v5 you can import `Alert` from `@mui/material`.

Answer (score 14):

The documentation examples show a code excerpt by default, but clicking on `<>` expands the full code including the imports. The `Alert` component is part of the [lab](https://material-ui.com/components/about-the-lab/) not the core. Components in the lab can have breaking changes with each release.

Here is how you import `Alert` and `AlertTitle`:

```
import Alert from '@material-ui/lab/Alert';
import AlertTitle from '@material-ui/lab/AlertTitle';
```

The lab is a separate npm/yarn install as indicated in the instructions here: https://material-ui.com/components/about-the-lab/#installation

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/lab

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/lab
```

Comment: but there is no lab folder in `node_modules/@material-ui/lab` it does not exist :(

Comment: I've added to my answer.

Comment: Material-UI should clean this up!  If "lab" is a separate module, why are its components described ( and used ) in the main documentation?  It's entirely not obvious that some components are from a separate module.

Comment: @NickPerkins All of the examples in the documentation show how to import the components. The components are under the "Lab" heading with an [About the lab](https://material-ui.com/components/about-the-lab/) section that describes this. What further steps do you think Material-UI should take?

Comment: It's just a point of confusion.  Once you know about "the lab", it's ok.  But if you don't know about "the lab" you probably think that all of the documented components are in "core", and you are probably surprised ( like me and the OP ) when something from the docs ( like "Alert" ) doesn't just work.  I love Material-UI, used it for years, but still got tripped-up by this.

Answer (score 0):

Since the release of [Material UI v5.0.0](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/releases/tag/v5.0.0), you can import `Alert` from `@mui/material` or `@mui/material/Alert`:

```js
import Alert from '@mui/material/Alert';
// or
import { Alert } from '@mui/material';
```

Here is the full [Alert API](https://mui.com/api/alert/).

Note: You can follow the [migration guide](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/) if you are upgrading from MUI v4 to MUI v5.